# Ideas to improve metadata count search

Tags: c#, search, nosql, metadata

I am working on a classified website, i am converting from sql server to mongodb/no-sql and probably node.js. I really want to come up with a better solution to the filtering of metadata (Eg the filter in ebay). I currently have all my metadata in a table

**Metadata Value Table**
AdvertID
MetaDataValue
PrentID
Level

So as you can see the metadata takes a hierarchical structure. I then perform group by count on this table to produce the filter count for the left pane of the site. Then as a user drills in to the metadata options i end up doing recursive group by count sub queries.

As you can imagine this gets a little costly on time and performance. As i am going to move no a no-sql option, i thought this would be a good time to investigate an alternative option. I am open to any suggestions, but this is hobby site so i would be looking for an open source/free solution.